# Modifying a .py file within Python

Tags: python, read-write

I have a program that imports a .py file that contains lists and dictionaries and uses them in the program. I am making another program that's purpose is to change the lists and dictionaries in this database .py file (either adding or removing parts of the lists/dictionaries). How would I go about doing this? Do i need to read in the .py file line by line, modify the lists, and overwrite the document? Is there a better way?

Any ideas would be much appreciated. If overwriting the file is the best plan, how do you do that?

Comment: is there a reason your DB is inside the .py-File? You might think about changing that. You could use a sqlite-DB or store data in a CSV-File, that saves you from that problem.

Comment: @kratenko From what I can understand, he isn't talking about huge amount of data. Just some lists/dictionaries and for that, in my opinion DBs are an overkill

Comment: That is correct. It just contains about 15 dictionaries and lists.

Comment: The reason it is a .py file is so that it can also be edited by hand by people who have little knowledge of coding.

Comment: @cole Well - then my next suggestion would have been JSON - but I think someone did that already... btw: keeping data away from code, if someone else is going to edit the data is always a good idea. Decreases the chances, other people break your program code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of directly editing py files within other py files, you should use the [Pickle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) module. Pickle module allows you to save objects (dictionaries, lists, etc.) in a file which is binary formatted. Then you can fetch those dictionaries or whatever you saved, from the file itself without anything else.

You can also use the [JSON](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) module if you want pure simplicity and data interchange.

Here's how you can do something similar with the JSON module:

```
>> import json
>> a = {'foo': 'bar', 'hello': 'jello'}
>> json.dumps(a)
>> '{"foo": "bar", "hello": "jello"}'
```

**NOTE:** The json module will turn any single quote into double quotes as JSON itself does not accept single quote. And also notice the 's' after 'dump'. It makes sure that the function returns pure string rather than any binary format.

Hope, that helps you :D

Comment: JSON is a better solution than pickle for just lists and dictionaries. Pickle is fairly awful.

Comment: @Sazid Will i have to use a json file type? Or will this module work with a .py file.

Comment: @Cole No, you can use any extension you like :)

The same applies for the pickle module too

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQLite or Pickle module instead, to allow easier data retrieval/manipulation from multiple programs/scripts.